# how to use variable instead of static in calling object in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is something like this is make able
i tried to put the var in [] but it didn't worked also
can any one help please
thank you

```js
const obj = { car : "a" , bus: "b" };
    const x = "car" ;
obj.x = "some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for computed property names?

```js
const obj = { car : "a" , bus: "b" };
    const x = "a" ;
obj[x] = "some value"
```